# При разрыве соединения повторять отправку каждые n-секунд

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Пошел по самому простому пути, вставил в блок error повторную отправку c тайм аутом.

```
function send() {  //отправка данных на сервер
            var message;
            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/Form',                   
                data: xml,

                success: function (responce) {                                          
                    SaveToLocal(true);                        
                    notification("Данные успешно отправлены","success");
                },

                error: function (xhr, str) {

                    SaveToLocal(false);
                    notification("Подключение недоступно, данные сохранены в локальном хранилище","warning");
                    setTimeout(DelayResend, 30 * 1000);
                }
            })

        };

function DelayResend() {

            for (var key in localStorage) { // цикл, о котором я говорил
                   resend1(key);     
                   }
                }

function resend(key) {         
                var message;
                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/Form',
                    data: xml,

                    success: function (responce) {
                        xml = NewStorage.getItem(key);
                        message = "Данные успешно отправлены";
                        NewStorage.removeItem(key);
                        notification(message);                          


                    },

                    error: function (xhr, str) {

                        setTimeout(DelayResend, 30 * 1000);

                    }
                })
            }
```

Но есть одно НО. Если соединения нет, то данные сохраняются и при повторной отправке - я передаю не один запрос, а все сохраненные данные в цикле. Таким образом функция повторной отправки setTimeout(DelayResend, 30 * 1000); вызывается несколько раз, и затем каждая из них вызывает следующую.

Прервать цикл при ошибке в первом же запросе - не могу, т.к весь  цикл выполняется раньше чем приходит ответ от ajax запроса.

Можно сначала проверить соединение, если его нет, - то повторный вызов, а если есть - то отправка. Этот  будет работать, но это костыль. Т.к. соединение может быть но данные не будут отправлены по другой причине, или отправятся не все. 
Приложение будет работать на планшете с нестабильным wi-fi соединением.

Comment: Можно сделать так, в случае ошибки сохранять в localStorage, а при каждой отправке проверять есть-ли что-то в localStorage и если есть то забирать данные оттуда и сначала отправлять их, или-же объединить данные и отправлять одним пакетом,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, основной смысл вы поймете. Ну я бы еще подумал, как объединить функции `send()` и `resend(key)`

```
function DelayResend() {
     var success = true;
     for (var key in localStorage) {
         succes &= resend(key);     
     }
     if (!success) {
         setTimeout(DelayResend, 30 * 1000);
     }
}

function resend(key) {         
      var message;
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/Form',
            data: xml,

            success: function (responce) {
                xml = NewStorage.getItem(key);
                message = "Данные успешно отправлены";
                NewStorage.removeItem(key);
                notification(message);                          
                return true;

            },
            error: function (xhr, str) {
                return false;
            }
      });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Правда непосредственно отправка все - равно запускается столько раз, сколько записей в хранилище. Но это уже не страшно. Главное - рекурсии больше нет.

Comment: Ну так и должно быть. Если хотите за один раз, тогда нужно формировать пакет из всех данных и слать всё сразу

Comment: А я вот задумался, почему &= вместо обычного присваивания?

Comment: @Pavel Saenko, потому что нам нужен суммарный результат всех отправок. Если хотя бы один не удался, то значение переменной равно `false`

Comment: Спасибо. Понял.